# SQL: When execution of a stored procedure fails from batch file

Tags: sql

I have multiple client PCs which have a version of SQL Express installed. These client PCs all have local databases that are periodically synced from the central database. This all works well.

I've created a stored procedure which updates the client databases (when tables change, etc). For this purpose I have created a batch file (sqlcmd).

My problem: when one of the local databases is not updated, because the stored procedure can not be executed (for example when the client PC is turned off or temporarily unavailable), there is no retry (it just fails).

Do you have any idea's how to target this problem so that all local databases are updated (even when a client PC isn't available at a certain time)?

Comment: Why don't you change, and run update from client machine and pull data from central server? Then you could set Windows task scheduler to run a batch file at certain time, or as soon as possible after the time has passed. You can also try running from Win Task on central server, that allows you to retry, but you'd have to manually check which DBs updated, and which not, if it's all in same file, as I assume

Comment: If you want to stick with push functionality then you just have to implement some kind of retry pattern right? I suggest you take a step up to Powershell as it's going to give you way more flexibility on this than batch files.